# WooCommerce : GET THE HTML OF A PRODUCT CARD FROM ITS ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin that displays products via a WP_Query request made asynchronously. I would like my asynchronous PHP script to send back the html code to the front-end page. Is there a function/method that gives the HTML of a product card from its id? For example :

```
<?php
$product_id = 42;
$html = wc_get_product_card_html($product_id);
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
$product_id = 42;
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$html = $product->get_card_html();
?>
```

I haven't found an equivalent yet...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$product->get_price_html()` is the function to get the product price as HTML.

Use the [WooCommerce code reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/) page to find the function and hooks reference.